# SQL inner join with slow order by performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, entity-framework, azure

We have an .NET application in Azure with one page that shows an overview of time entries. We use Entity Framework to build and execute the SQL queries. When we sort by a column of the time table (like date or hours) it's fast enough. But when we sort on a column thats from an other table (from an inner join, like the user diplayname) its really slow.

Also when we look in our Azure portal in the DTU metrics (after this query) its peaked to 100% DTU. We have P4 service plan with 500 DTU's, so don't must be an problem I think.

This is an example of an slow query thats get execute by Entity Framework:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Project1].[Date] AS [Date], 
[Project1].[Hours] AS [Hours], 
[Project1].[Notes] AS [Notes], 
[Project1].[StartEnd] AS [StartEnd], 
[Project1].[Status] AS [Status], 
[Project1].[Timer] AS [Timer], 
[Project1].[TimeRowId] AS [TimeRowId], 
[Project1].[InvoiceId] AS [InvoiceId], 
[Project1].[Pause] AS [Pause], 
[Project1].[ClientStatus] AS [ClientStatus], 
[Project1].[ExternalUrl] AS [ExternalUrl], 
[Project1].[ExternalName] AS [ExternalName], 
[Project1].[ApprovedBy] AS [ApprovedBy], 
[Project1].[ApprovedDate] AS [ApprovedDate], 
[Project1].[ClientApprovedBy] AS [ClientApprovedBy], 
[Project1].[ClientApprovedDate] AS [ClientApprovedDate]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Extent1].[Hours] AS [Hours], 
    [Extent1].[Notes] AS [Notes], 
    [Extent1].[StartEnd] AS [StartEnd], 
    [Extent1].[Status] AS [Status], 
    [Extent1].[Timer] AS [Timer], 
    [Extent1].[TimeRowId] AS [TimeRowId], 
    [Extent1].[InvoiceId] AS [InvoiceId], 
    [Extent1].[Pause] AS [Pause], 
    [Extent1].[ClientStatus] AS [ClientStatus], 
    [Extent1].[ExternalUrl] AS [ExternalUrl], 
    [Extent1].[ExternalName] AS [ExternalName], 
    [Extent1].[ApprovedBy] AS [ApprovedBy], 
    [Extent1].[ApprovedDate] AS [ApprovedDate], 
    [Extent1].[ClientApprovedBy] AS [ClientApprovedBy], 
    [Extent1].[ClientApprovedDate] AS [ClientApprovedDate], 
    [Extent6].[DisplayName] AS [DisplayName]
    FROM      [dbo].[Time] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[TimeRow] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TimeRowId] = [Extent2].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[ProjectUser] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[ProjectUserId] = [Extent3].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Project] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[ProjectId] = [Extent4].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Customer] AS [Extent5] ON [Extent4].[CustomerId] = [Extent5].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[User] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent3].[UserId] = [Extent6].[Id]
    WHERE ([Extent5].[CompanyId] = @p__linq__0) AND (@p__linq__1 <= [Extent1].[Date]) AND (@p__linq__2 >= [Extent1].[Date])
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[DisplayName] DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 25 ROWS ONLY ',N'@p__linq__0 int,@p__linq__1 datetime2(7),@p__linq__2 datetime2(7)',@p__linq__0=19218,@p__linq__1='2017-01-01 00:00:00',@p__linq__2='2017-12-31 00:00:00'
```

We tried to add an nonclustered index on displayname (of the user table), but that didn't make any differents. Also we have automatic tuning on in Azure on the database, so you must think Azure adds the necessary indexes it self, right?

How can we make this query perform?

**COMMENT 05-12-2017** 
I think we fixed the problem. We execute the query in Database Tuning Adviser and got 9 recommended indexes. After we apply this recommendations the query is really fast!

Comment: Can you provide the actual execution plan? Or the table structures and indexes?

Comment: At a minimum there is a problem with your paging.  For your paging to be stable, you need to order the rows completely.  Sorting first by the key columns of your tables is both required, and may improve performance, as you won't have to sort the _whole_ result by User.DisplayName.

Comment: *so you must think Azure adds the necessary indexes it self* That's something you should check, not assume. It's quite important if all foreign key are indexed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your question on how to make the query faster, as Sean Lange states, we'd need the table structure and execution plan for that.

I'm not very experienced with Azure, but you should see any indexes being used.

This document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-advisor

> Indexes created using recommendations are always flagged as
>   auto_created indexes. You can see which indexes are auto_created by
>   looking at sys.indexes view.

That document may help you find if any indexes are being created for you by Azure or if you need to accept any suggestions.